# How to style Antd component

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, styled-components

I am working on Switch component with antd library. I would like to change background of switch, so I have following code:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Switch as SwitchhAnt } from 'antd';

export const Button = styled(SwitchhAnt)`
    .ant-switch-checked {
        background-color: red;
    }
`
```

But switch background does not change at all. I know I can wrap this in some container and it will works but why something like that does not works?

Answer (score 0):

As per how styled components work under the hood,

1. **It creates a unique class name by hashing styles into a seemingly-random string, like *dKamQW* or *iDwMsQ***.
2. **Then inject a new CSS class into the page, using that hashed string as its name, and containing all of the CSS declarations from the styles string.** You can see that when you inspect switch that different style classes have been applied.

**Normal antd Switch**
[image]

**Styled antd Switch**
[image]

So here you don't need to add the class name used by antd. Just only need to add CSS properties that need to have like below.

```
export const Button = styled(SwitchAnt)`
    background-color: red;
  // ....... other styles  
`
```

You can check example codesandbox in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-switch-antd-72687446-zoggvv?file=/StyledBtn.js).

You can also refer [demystifying-styled-components](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/demystifying-styled-components/) and [how-styled-components-works](https://medium.com/styled-components/how-styled-components-works-618a69970421) for more details about what styled components do under the hood.